# VSCode Insiders intellisense suggestions are all grey

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am currently using VSCode Insiders on my Dell XPS 17. I believe I hit some sort of keyboard shortcut and all of my intellisense suggestions turned grey. No matter whether I switched projects or straight out uninstalled and reinstalled, the suggestions are all grey while the rest of my interface is the correct color.

I recently tested on my other computer also running VSCode Insiders and with settings sync with this computer. The colors including intellisense suggestions are all the correct colors there.

I have attached a photo of what I'm seeing. If anyone knows what this is help would be greatly appreciated!

[Grey Intellisense Suggestions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Aq3R1.png)

Comment: Upon looking more into this, it seems that this is an "issue" with VSCode Insiders itself. That other computer I was testing on upon updating vscode now also has the grey icons

Comment: The Issue's progress can be tracked at https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/107276